# .NET 5 "Could not find a part of the path"

Tags: nuget, .net-5, nuget-package-restore

I cloned .NET 5 project, which should be working (unfortunately, I can't provide the project so you could reproduce the problem). I didn't change anything, I just wanted to build it, however, I am getting this error when restoring packages (although the project itself is on different disk, I found out that this is "global-packages" folder):

```html
Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Users\me\.nuget\packages\microsoft.aspnetcore.azureappservices.siteextension\5.0.5\content\store\x64\net5.0\microsoft.extensions.configuration.environmentvariables\5.0.0\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables.dll'
```

However, I don't think it is a problem with this particular dll, as my colleague cloned the same project and he is getting the same error, but with different library.

This is what I've already tried doing:

- Clearing all nuget cache
- Checking "automatically check for missing packages during build in visual studio"
- Updating everything I could (VS, nuget..)
- Running VS as Administrator
- Checking package sources (yes, nuget.org is there)
- Adding "add key="repositoryPath" value="$..\..\packages"" into the nuget.config file - this didn't actually create the package folder in the defined path
- Clean/rebuild/... everything

I think, that the problem will be in some setting, but I have no idea, where to look :/

Comment: Smells like it could be a long path issue https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/cli-reference/cli-ref-long-path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the command **dotnet restore**
instead of
**dotnet nuget**